# Rails action don't redirect me to a external page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, external-links

I have this link to redirect to google is a example , i just need to go to the controller and then make some insert in database and redirect to a torrent link but in the example just show google

```
<%= link_to "Link", {:controller => "home", :action => "index", :link=> "www.google.com" }%>
```

when i press the link i continue to the following action

```
> def index
>     @link = params[:link]
>     if @link.present?
>       return redirect_to @link
>     end 
> end
```

but the action don't redirect me to www.google.com just go to this direction

> localhost:3000/?link=www.google.com

how can i go to www.google.com and redirect well ?

Comment: You should specify link with protocol: http: //www.google.com

Comment: why use redirect here? why not just use an anchor tag? is it to hit a controller when following an external link?

Comment: Also, your `link_to` code doesn't seem to have a `params[:link]`...  Is it referring to `params[:car]` which you're defining as 'www.google.com'?

Answer (score 1):

I just need to specified the protocol in this case http

Now is working with this

```
<%= link_to "Link", {:controller => "home", :action => "index", :link => "http://www.google.cl" }%>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are looking for this:

```
<%= link_to "Link", "http://www.google.com" %>
```

Hope I could help.

Comment: i want to go to the controller first to make some inserts on the db and then redirect to some torrent link google was just a example

Comment: humm.. ok now I got it. I thought you weren't doing anything in your controller so there was no need to pass through it.